# How can I turn off a frozen iPhone?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 5 is frozen. I cannot turn it off and 
when I try to restore it wont let me because it says I need to turn off Find My iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that you can try is doing a hard shutdown by holding both the power button and the home button for at least ten seconds. If your device still does not turn on or respond, you can try putting it into DFU Mode (recovery mode). To do this, start by plugging your device into your computer with the USB cable. Then hold the power button for around 5 seconds. While you are still holding the power button, press and hold the home button for an additional 10 seconds. At this time, release the power button but keep holding the home button for around 15 seconds. At this point, iTunes should recognize your phone as a device in recovery mode. To exit recovery mode, hold the power button and the home buttons until the device begins booting.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the home and power button for 5-10 seconds, it should reboot, after it boots up, shut it down the usual way by holding the power button and sliding to off.

Answer (score 0):

You could also manually disconnect the battery by removing the two bottom screws and then lifting the screen.

Once screen is up, unscrew and remove the battery connector shield and then disconnect battery flex. Re attach after a few seconds or when ready!

Answer (score -1):

1. Reset All Settings can help if you’re still not sure which app is causing your iPhone to freeze. Reset All Settings resets your iPhone settings to their factory defaults, but it doesn’t delete any data. You’ll have to reenter your Wi-Fi password and configure the Settings app again, but Reset All Settings can fix a frozen iPhone, and it’s a lot less work than erasing and restoring your iPhone from a backup. To reset your iPhone to factory default settings, go to Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset All Settings.
2. Try some recovery tool.
   [How to Fix iPhone Frozen on Apple Screen](http://www.recovery-tool.com/ios-recovery/iphone-frozen-on-apple-screen.html)

Comment: How can you acces the settings menu on a frozen phone?